# Fullcalendar event from laravel query json don't show up

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, fullcalendar

I have some problem with Fullcalendar on laravel framework.

My Code looks like this:

Scripts to call event when fullcalendar loads:

```
eventSources:
[
  {
    type:'POST',
    url: '/hotel/public/api/checkFullCalendar',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {                 
      "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    }                    
  }
]
```

This is my Controller:

```
public function checkFullCalendar(Request $request) {

    $today = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    $reservation = Reservation::where('checkin','>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())->get();

    $events = array();

    foreach ($reservation as $reser) {
      $e = array();
      $e['id'] = $reser->id;
      $e['title'] = "Test";
      $e['start'] = $reser->checkin;
      $e['end'] = $reser->checkout;

      array_push($events, $e);
    }   

    return response()->json(['events' , $events]);
}
```

This is the output:

```
["events",[{"id":1,"title":"Test","start":"2017-09-01","end":"2017-09-02"},{"id":2,"title":"Test","start":"2017-09-01","end":"2017-09-02"},{"id":3,"title":"Test","start":"2017-09-01","end":"2017-09-03"}]]
```

and it don't throw any error and no event is show on calendar ,.. BUT,
if i change my query for only 1 record like this is work

```
public function checkFullCalendar(Request $request) {

    $today = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    $reservation = Reservation::where('checkin','>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())->first();

    $events = array();

    $events['id'] = $reservation->id;
    $events['title'] = "Test";
    $events['start'] = $reservation->checkin;
    $events['end'] = $reservation->checkout;


    return response()->json(['events' , $events]);
}
```

it work perfectly fine(output below) if only I have 1 record I guess I have to style the array output wrong any idea what I missing here? thank you

```
["events",{"id":1,"title":"Test","start":"2017-09-01"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output must just be a single array like this:

```
[
  {"id":1,"title":"Test","start":"2017-09-01","end":"2017-09-02"}
  {"id":2,"title":"Test","start":"2017-09-01","end":"2017-09-02"}
  {"id":3,"title":"Test","start":"2017-09-01","end":"2017-09-03"}
]
```

without the outer array round it. fullCalendar is looking for event objects in the root of the outer array. It thinks the whole response is the event array, it does not expect to have to look in an arbitrary element of an outer array.

I don't know Laravel, but I would think that writing

```
return response()->json($events);
```

in your controller would produce the correct result.

P.S. The reason it works with one event is just luck - you've got a single array, it will loop through them and probably ignores the first element (the string "events") because it's not a valid event object and then manages to the display the second element because it is valid. Whereas when the second element is also an array it doesn't know what to do - it was expecting event objects directly, not in a sub-array.

Comment: No problem. If the answer has helped you please remember to upvote it and/or marked as the accepted answer - thanks :-)